# Upload image in CKEditor (django)

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

I add CKEditor to my model in django. But I can't figure out how to force CKEditor to upload image from my computer. I tried to use:

https://github.com/nephila/django-ckeditor-filebrowser-filer

https://github.com/IMGIITRoorkee/django-filemanager

but without any luck

Maybe someone, who did this before, can give me direction